# MediaPlayer just stop playing suddenly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

Hello StackOverFlow Community, I have this problem lately that I have created a Whack A Mole game and then sometimes the sound stop playing by itself and it show this error only, I search on the internet and it says use `OnPrepared` for MediaPlayer, I do not know how it works yet

> E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x7897fe1440)\

or

> E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)

**This is my GameActivity**

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

public MediaPlayer mPlayerShot;
public MediaPlayer mPlayerMiss;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    mTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimeVal);
    mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScoreVal);

    // Get saved difficulty, default to Medium if no pref exists
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    currentDiff = sharedPref.getString("saved_difficulty", "Medium");

    // Start the game!
    mTimer.start();
    handler.post(moleLoop);

    varClose = false;

    mPlayerShot = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.playerlaser);
    mPlayerMiss = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.enemylaser);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    // Scale mole translation based on device dimensions
    int sHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    yValue = (sHeight/8)*-1;

}

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    varClose = true;
    mTimer.cancel();

    mPlayerShot.stop();
    mPlayerMiss.stop();

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    varClose = true;
    mTimer.cancel();

    mPlayerShot.stop();
    mPlayerMiss.stop();

}

public Runnable moleLoop = new Runnable() {

    int varPrevRandMole = 10;

    @Override
    public void run () {

        // Pick a mole at random, if you get the same twice, re-roll until it's different
        varRandMole = new Random().nextInt(8);

        if (varRandMole == varPrevRandMole){
            do
                varRandMole = new Random().nextInt(8);
            while (varRandMole == varPrevRandMole);
        }

        varPrevRandMole = varRandMole;

        // Pop the mole up
        molesClick[varRandMole].animate().translationY(yValue).setDuration(moleUpTime);

        // Timer to pop our mole back down if player fails to hit it
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                if (!varClose) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        if (molesClick[i].getTranslationY() == yValue) {

                            final int j = i;

                            // Sets the mole back to its beginning position
                            // run this update on the UI thread as we need a "looper" thread
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    molesClick[j].animate().translationY(0).setDuration(5);
                                }
                            });

                            if (mPlayerMiss.isPlaying() && mPlayerMiss != null) {
                                mPlayerMiss.stop();
                                mPlayerMiss.reset();
                                mPlayerMiss.release();
                            }
                            mPlayerMiss.start();

                            // Deduct a life if we miss a mole
                            varLives -= 1;
                            updateLives(varLives);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, timeInterval);

        if (!varClose) {
            handler.postDelayed(moleLoop, timeInterval);
        }
    }
};

public void directHit(){

    if (mPlayerShot != null && mPlayerShot.isPlaying()){
        mPlayerShot.stop();
        mPlayerShot.reset();
        mPlayerShot.release();
    }

    mPlayerShot = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.playerlaser);
    mPlayerShot.start();

    // Award points, update score
    varScore += 250;
    updateScore(varScore);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
mPlayerShot.prepare();
before 
mPlayerShot.start();

Comment: It said that Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException, I think you missed something in the code

Answer (score 0):

Here are few problems I noticed .

You must create mediaplayer again after release

```
   // first check null
if (mPlayerMiss != null && mPlayerMiss.isPlaying()) {
          mPlayerMiss.stop()
          mPlayerMiss.reset();
          mPlayerMiss.release();
        }
      //creating media player again here
      mPlayerMiss= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.playermissfilename);
      mPlayerMiss.start();
```

In onPause method you are calling `mediaPlayer.stop();` method . Check for null and better call `mediaPlayer.release()` instead stop .

You are calling `mediaPlayer.stop()` inside `onPause()` so no need to call again in `onStop()`

if you are still facing issue (not the best way ) ,use try/catch while stopping and resetting player

```
if (mPlayerMiss.isPlaying() && mPlayerMiss != null) {
  try {
       mPlayerMiss.stop();
       mPlayerMiss.reset();
       mPlayerMiss.release();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Comment: this is the error "E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -19)"

Comment: and they show another error E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1010)

Answer (score 0):

There are two uses of MediaPlayer, the one you have used which is the "light" one that does not give many options for handling. The other one is much more sophisticated and much better to my opinion. Below I load mywavfile.wav from raw resources directory. Do not forget to add

"MediaPlayer player" as a field in your class but not a local variable.

```
try {
     Log.w("Myonabler", "set media player");
     player = new MediaPlayer();
     int resourceInt = R.raw.mywavfile;
     final AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resourceInt);
     player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
     afd.close();
     //player.setLooping(true);
     player.prepare();
     Log.w("Myonabler", "set media player 2");
     player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.w("Myonabler", "Audio released");
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
            player.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Myonabler", "Exception 1 voice");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```